# Secure content-defined chunking

Tags: hash, performance, universal-hash

## Intro

For deduplication purposes, I need to split a stream of plaintext bytes into variable-sized chunks. The way this is traditionally done is using a rolling hash function defined over some window $w$ (e.g. 48 bytes). This window "slides" along the byte stream and is evaluated at each byte position, and when the value of the function is let's say $f(w) \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 1024)$ a cutpoint is made, marking the end of the current chunk and beginning of the next one. The hash function is extremely fast to evaluate when the following is known:

- The value of the rolling hash function at some window position
- The byte entering the window
- The byte leaving the window

---

## The issue

Now if I encrypt each chunk and upload it to the server, I already leak some information about the plaintext:

- The adversary knows that the hash value (a simple CRC32-like checksum) of the last $w$ bytes of each plaintext chunk $\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 1024)$
- All the other windows are hashed to a value $\not\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 1024)$.

---

## Related

[Here is a similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16082/cryptographically-secure-keyed-rolling-hash-function), but it seems people there did not realize that the hash value (output of the rolling hash function) is never published or known to the attacker. The only information disclosed is whether the hash value $\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 1024)$ (true or false) for every window position in the input plaintext stream. So they recommend to use [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) or $AES(f(w)) \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 1024)$, but both solutions are just too slow compared to using the plain rolling hash.

There seem to be similarities with the [hash-table flooding attacks](https://emboss.github.io/blog/2012/12/14/breaking-murmur-hash-flooding-dos-reloaded/), as the hash value is also never directly published. Besides the already-mentioned SipHash, Microsoft has proposed [Marvin32](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130262421) for this particular issue.

---

## Questions

1. Besides the already mentioned solutions, what is the proper way to perform chunking without leaking information about the plaintext? Performance is **very critical** here though.
2. Would [UMAC](http://fastcrypto.org/umac/) or [Universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) have any application here?
3. Would [this rolling hash function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347240/how-to-attack-universal-hash-function-based-on-finite-field-arithmetic) solve the information leakage on its own without encrypting the hash value with `AES/SipHash`? If not, what can be done to fix the information leakage? Pseudo-code for this hash function:

   ```
   // My secret key, never shared or disclosed to anyone
   var key = ....; 

   // Generate substitution table
   var substitution = new uint32[256];
   var substitutionKey = HMAC(key, SUBSTITUTION_SALT);
   for (uint32 i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
   {
       var randomBytes = HMAC(substitutionKey, UInt32ToBytes(i));
       substitution[i] = BytesToUInt32(randomBytes);
   }

   // Generate random irreducible polynomial of degree 33 (GF 2) and store it
   // in a 32-bit register (33 coefficients, but the 33rd is implied because
   // it's always 1)
   // The algorithm is not shown here due to its complexity, but let's assume
   // the polynomial is derived from the key
   var polynomialKey = HMAC(key, POLYNOMIAL_SALT);
   uint32 polynomial = RandomIrreduciblePolynomial33(polynomialKey);

   // Hash an input window
   uint8[] window = new uint8[48];
   LoadPlaintext(ref window);
   uint32 hash = 0;
   for (uint32 i = 0; i < 48; i++)
   {
       // Galois multiplication by x and subsequent reduction
       hash = (hash << 1) ^ ((hash >> 31) * polynomial);
       // Add the substitution polynomial
       hash = hash ^ substitution[window[i]];
   }

   ...

   // Now if we want to move the window forward by a single byte, there
   // exist a very efficient algorithm that does that, but it's not
   // relevant to the issue at hand
   ```

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at BLAKE2sp?

Comment: @SOJPM: Thanks, I will check it out. But after a quick investigation of the [SipHash paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/351.pdf), they compared SipHash to BLAKE-512, and SipHash turned out to be 5.5 times faster than BLAKE-512 for 64 byte messages (BLAKE-512 has 16 rounds vs 2 rounds of SipHash). I wonder if Blake2sp improves the situation so much on 32-bit platforms as to get ahead in terms of performance.

Comment: BLAKE2SP is the parallelized version of BLAKE2S which is the faster Version of BLAKE-256 which is 32-bit based. (Like SHA-256 vs SHA-512)

Comment: Looking at the [Blake2s](https://goo.gl/ExrG2u) and [Blake2sp](https://goo.gl/IexRKB), there is no way for them to be faster than [SipHash](https://goo.gl/tXXybu) simply by comparing the amount of computation done per round and the number of rounds (2 vs 10), unless I would target 16-core processors, in which case the parallel computation might begin to catch up. SipHash and [Blake2](https://blake2.net/) were both made by Jean-Philippe Aumasson, and SipHash was specifically designed for hashing short messages unlike Blake2. Also, Blake2s is not available for my platform (C#).

Answer (score 5):

UMAC uses AES, so it will not lead to a faster algorithm than the rolling hash + AES solution suggested in the previous question. Universal hashing based MACs like UMAC and Poly1305 usually use a PRF (which you could just use directly) to hide the hash. There are universal hashing MACs that do not, but as far as I know they are even slower. (Further, I am not sure if a secure MAC would even be enough, or if you actually need a PRF.)

Without leaking any more information, there are not many options. Rolling hash + SipHash is probably faster anywhere that you lack AES hardware, but that may be the best you can do.

If you find the performance cost to be unacceptable, you might want to allow *some* information to leak. For example, if you define chunking using `parity(w) = 0` and then `PRF(k, f(w)) mod (n / 2) = 0`, you halve the number of PRF calls while only leaking one extra bit of information on the window (and even less for those positions where you did not end a chunk).

You can of course reveal even more information to reduce the number of calls further, but in the end you back at something leaks as much as just using `f(w) mod n = 0`.

Comment: The reason why I mentioned UMAC and universal hashing is that it might be enough to use the universal hashing directly, without the final step of AES/PRF. That's because in the case of deduplication, an attacker never gets to see the output of the hash function. I tried to illustrate attacks against such a model [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347240/how-to-attack-universal-hash-function-based-on-finite-field-arithmetic) - I am yet to find any attacks. And if it's a secure construction (for that specific application), it completely solves all performance issues.

Comment: @Paya, if that is secure, then yes, it could be faster. I cannot answer the linked question, however, so I don't know if it is.